# Code for copy data using VbA code in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

How can I fix the below code for below snapshots?

I have tried below code

```
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim Rng5 As Range

For Each Rng3 In CurCell_1


   For Each Rng5 In CurCell_3

          lLFs = VBA.Len(Rng3) - VBA.Len(VBA.Replace(Rng3, vbLf, ""))

     If lLFs > 0 Then

        Range("B27").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("AccountModule").Select
        Range("AY2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

      End If
   Next
Next
```

but the same is not working.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgX6l.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spTJ2.jpg)

Comment: Never ask for (free) code. on SO...You won't get any. Please visit [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim Rng5 As Range

For Each Rng3 In CurCell_1


   For Each Rng5 In CurCell_3

          lLFs = VBA.Len(Rng3) - VBA.Len(VBA.Replace(Rng3, vbLf, ""))

     If lLFs > 0 Then

        Range("B27").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("AccountModule").Select
        Range("AY2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

      End If
   Next
Next

Comment: this code I have tried but not wroking

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Comment: code added in the section

Comment: rory.ap can you please look into this code

Comment: Where are you setting `CurrCell_1` and `CurCell_3`?  I'm not sure how those ranges(?) correspond to the data you have shown.  And how do the cells B27 and AY2 fit into things?  And what do you mean when you say that the code "is not working"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a different kind of routine like this one:

```
Sub separ8(src, trg)
 Dim r As Range, ar
 For Each r In src.Rows
   ar = Split(r.Cells(1, 2), Chr(10))
   For Each el In ar
     trg.Value = r.Cells(1, 1)
     trg.Offset(0, 1) = el
     Set trg = trg.Offset(1)
   Next el
 Next r
End Sub
```

My sub assumes that your input data is in a range given by `src` and the results should be written into a range starting at `trg`.

So, when there is data like this

```
  A   B      C
1
2     abc    123
             456
             789
3     xyz    1234
             456789
             78941
```

The procedure call

```
separ8 [b2:c3],[b7]
```

will get you this result:

```
   A    B    C
 6
 7      abc  123
 8      abc  456
 9      abc  789
10      xyz  1234
11      xyz  456789
12      xyz  78941
```